# Why does Option require explicit toList inside for loops?

Tags: scala, scala-option

Using a for loop with a simple Option works:

```
scala> for (lst <- Some(List(1,2,3))) yield lst
res68: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

But looping over the contents of the Option does not:

```
scala> for (lst <- Some(List(1,2,3)); x <- lst) yield x
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
              for (lst <- Some(List(1,2,3)); x <- lst) yield x
                                               ^
```

...unless the Option is explicitly converted to a List:

```
scala> for (lst <- Some(List(1,2,3)).toList; x <- lst) yield x
res66: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Why is the explicit list conversion needed? Is this the idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for (lst <- Some(List(1,2,3)); x <- lst) yield x
```

is translated to

```
Some(List(1,2,3)).flatMap(lst => lst.map(x => x))
```

The `flatMap` method on `Option` expects a function that returns an `Option`, but you're passing a function that returns a `List` and there is no implicit conversion from `List` to `Option`.

Now if you convert the `Option` to a list first, the `flatMap` method of `List` will be called instead, which expects a function returning a `List`, which is what you are passing to it.

In this particular case, I think the most idiomatic solution is

```
Some(List(1,2,3)).flatten.toList
```

Comment: Which is why `for (lst <- Some(List(1,2,3)) get; x <- Option(lst)) yield x` works too.  Interesting.